# How to Create a 3D Plot From Table with Date and Time Value?

Tags: r, plot, 3d

I am new to R, and try to get a visual representation of a year collected temperature data from a server rack. The data is already prepared and loaded in the `data` object in the R environment in this format:

```
> str(data)
'data.frame':   516496 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ Day         : POSIXct, format: "2017-06-29" "2017-06-29" "2017-06-29" "2017-06-29" ...
 $ SecondsOfDay: int  0 60 120 180 240 300 360 420 480 540 ...
 $ Temp        : num  34.8 34.7 34.7 34.7 34.7 ...
```

The field `Day` contains just the date, the field `SecondsOfDay` is the second of the day, rounded to full minutes. The field `Temp` contains the actual temperature value.

I would like to create a 3D plot of this data, where the X-axis is the date, and the Y-axis the time of the day. The Z-axis should be the temperature.

Ideally, I would like to use one of the basic functions like `persp` to create a graph like this (but with correct Z values):

[image]

The core of my problem, why I could not find a own solution yet, is because the examples for the plot use a function and range sequences as input. I do not understand how to prepare the data from my table into the correct format for the plot functions.

**What is a simple way to generate a plot as described above?**

Comment: plotly can be a nice tool for a 3d surface - see https://plot.ly/r/3d-surface-plots/ if you have the data frame the plot would be something like p<-plot_ly(x=data.frame$Date, y=data.frame$SecondsOfDay, z=data.frame$Temp) %>% add_surface() then to see the chart print(p)

Comment: I'd rather look into [`rgl`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgl/index.html) because it's not-proprietary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No fancy shading, but this should give you an idea

```
d <- rep(1:5, each=10)
m <- rep((0:9)*144, 5)
v <- sin(seq(0, 1, length.out=50)*2*pi*5) + (1:50)/50

temperature <- matrix(v, ncol=10, byrow=TRUE)

par(mar=c(2, 2, 2, 2))

day <- unique(d)
tod <- unique(m)/60

persp(day, tod, temperature, theta=50, phi=20,
  ticktype="detailed", ylab="Time of day (hr)")
```

[image]

Essentially you spread out the temperature values in a matrix with dimensions taken from the date and minute vectors.
I can never quite remember whether it's `byrow=TRUE` or `FALSE`, and what vector decides which dimension, so I just check by eye and change things up until it looks right.

A couple of other options

```
library(plot3D) # an extension of persp()
persp3D(day, tod, temperature, theta=50, phi=20)

library(rgl) # also similar to persp(), but interactive
persp3d(day, tod, temperature, col=cm.colors(100))
```